# Saving file to a different directory in php

Tags: php

I have 2 directories in "Members" directory

```
Members
     Admin
     Users
```

in the Admin directory there is a php script that is receiving Http POST request and saving the contents into a file , but the file name is the first value of POST request.

**How can I save the contents to User directory instead of Admin directory**

**This is my attempt but it gives error :**

```
<?php
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$filn = $_POST["account"];
$size =  count($_POST);
file_put_contents('./Users/'.$filn , file_get_contents('php://input')); 
?>
```

**Error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$filn" in C:\xampp\htdocs\auth\Admin\add.php on line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows-

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__."/../Users/$filn", $entityBody);
```